# Spring Boot MongoDB - MongoDB cannot generate 'ID'

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I have some problem with my Spring Boot application.
When I save one document in my repository application works fine, but when I save more than one documents, my aplication not working. Here is my code.

**Article.java**

```
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;

public class Article {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private String title;
    private String description;

    public Article() {}

    public Article(String title, String description) {
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Article{" +
                "id='" + id + '\'' +
                ", title='" + title + '\'' +
                ", description='" + description + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

**ArticleRepository.java**

```
public interface ArticleRepository extends MongoRepository<Article, String> {}
```

**DatabaseLoader.java**

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Component
public class DatabaseLoader implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private ArticleRepository articleRepository;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        articleRepository.deleteAll();

        // example 1: if I save one document to my repo everything works fine
        // example: articleRepository.save(new Article("Title 1", "description 1"));
        // console returns: Article{id='596f480e4e118123574a13f1', title='Title 1', description='description 1'}


        // but here is problem
        Set<Article> articleList = new HashSet<Article>(){
            {
                add(new Article("Title 1", "description 1"));
                add(new Article("Title 2", "description 2"));
            }
        };

        // because if I try to save my collection
        articleRepository.save(articleList);

        // console returns: com.mongodb.DuplicateKeyException: 
        // Write failed with error code 11000 and error message 
        // 'insertDocument :: caused by :: 11000 E11000 duplicate key
        // error index: test.article.$user  dup key: { : null }'
        System.out.println(articleRepository.findAll());
    }
}
```

**Application.java**

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SimpleMongoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Do you know, why I have this problem?
Thank you for all your answers.

Comment: Add @Document(collection = "colletion-name") to POJO, I mean Article class

Comment: Oh my god, it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

OK, here is @Afridi's **solution**.

All you need to do is adding `@Document(collection="collection-name")` annotation in your document. here is an example:

```
@Document(collection = "articles") // here is solution
public class Article {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String title;
    private String description;

    //getters, setters and constructor
}
```